# Unzipping data files on install of python project

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have a python project which contains some largish data files as part of the distribution. I would like to distribute these data files in zip/gzip form and then have them unpacked on install. I'm using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to manage the project dependencies and publish to the repository, so I assume I need to hook into the generated `setup.py` somehow, but not sure how to do this.

Note that for various reasons, doing this at runtime is not an option (or at least highly undesirable).

Comment: For confirmation... these data files are zipped inside the project's distribution (which is already zipped itself)? If yes, why?

Comment: They are compressed because the uncompressed version is 6GB.

Comment: Aren't Python wheels (and sdists) already compressed?

Comment: So your suggestion is to decompress before building, and then recompress during build? It seems a bit clunky but it might work.

Comment: I guess maybe that is what I am suggesting. Maybe try with a small sample of your data. Leave it uncompressed in a sub-package of the source code repository. Let Poetry (or whatever tool) build the wheel and/or sdist. Then check the size of the wheel and/or sdist. Is that compressed enough?

Answer (score 1):

The generated `setup.py` just exists for historical reasons, when `pip` wasn't able to understand PEP-518. It is not used anymore by any up-to-date tool and will be removed in the future.

There is no such thing like post-installation tasks in poetry and probably never will be.

The recommended way of doing it, is to provide a [scripts entry point](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts) that is doing the job and instruct users to run this command after the installation.